# How to get the Overall Categories, Sub Categories in Amazon MWS?

Tags: amazon-mws

Hi I'm started the web development in Amazon MWS. I need to integrate the get category list, add product, list product etc in my application. I have referred the documentation, http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_IN/products/Products_Overview.html But, in that document there is no option to get all the categories, sub categories in mws. And also i have referred several sites, they told me to refer the Browse Tree Report in MWS Api. But, there is no section in the report section. Is Amazon MWS have something like "Get Categories" method, or is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

For simple to use and explore checkout
https://www.browsenodes.com

It also has option to browse the categories for other countries.
Example for India the URL is
https://www.browsenodes.com/amazon.in

Answer (score 2):

You can get the categories for a market place api by requesting Browse tree report. Each browse node( Amazon way of storing categories ) contains a field child_nodes which gives you information about the sub categories.

> http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_IN/reports/Reports_ReportType.html#ReportTypeCategories__BrowseTreeReports

If you are looking for the categories of individual product. Please refer

> http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_IN/products/Products_GetProductCategoriesForSKU.html
>   http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_IN/products/Products_GetProductCategoriesForASIN.html

Answer (score 1):

The Browse Tree Guide is an Excel file available for download from the Amazon Seller Central. Once logged in, go to `Seller Central Help` > `Manage Inventory` > `Reference` > `Browse Tree Guide`

Comment: @CharlesSelvaraj I am not aware that such an API exists

Comment: As Hazzit said, there is no API method for categories. Besides, they don't change the categories often, so it wouldn't be worth making calls for these anyways because of the limits in API calls per minute. You can import those into your database once and reuse it for years.

Answer (score 1):

I tried in amazon mws scratchpad and could get category information. (scratchpad website: https://mws.amazonservices.com.au/scratchpad/index.html) . 
The process of getting categories:

- API section Reports -> RequestReport (report type:_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_, report option: _GET_XML_BROWSE_TREE_DATA_)
- GetReportList(in this list, you may find ReportId related with '_GET_XML_BROWSE_TREE_DATA_' )
- GetReport(use this ReportId as input).

  Then you can get the tree report for all categories

Comment: What worked for me was to use the url https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html instead of https://mws.amazonservices.com.au/scratchpad/index.html i.e. without the ".au" after the ".com".

Answer (score 0):

Amazon does not make it easy to get all the categories, but I think what you are looking for is actually in AWS Browse Nodes.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/BrowseNodes.html

Comment: Dead link. New link available?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a little late but i wanted to answer the question so some other ones 
find useful. First, you need to make a request to RequestReport action, after that, you will make a request to GetRequest action using previous action's id, this will give you a long list of the categories (for the marketplaces you specified in the query). [This](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/reports/Reports_RequestReport.html) is the link to the action & service, and also don't forget to take a look at [ReportTypes](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/reports/Reports_ReportType.html) enums, you must define them correctli.

```
POST /Reports/2009-01-01 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: mws.amazonservices.com
User-Agent: <Your User Agent Header>

AWSAccessKeyId=0PB842EXAMPLE7N4ZTR2
&Action=RequestReport
&EndDate=2008-06-26T18%3A12%3A21
&MWSAuthToken=amzn.mws.4ea38b7b-f563-7709-4bae-87aeaEXAMPLE
&Marketplace=ATVPDKIKX0DER
&ReportType=_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_
&SellerId=A1XEXAMPLE5E6
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
&SignatureVersion=2
&StartDate=2009-01-03T18%3A12%3A21
&Timestamp=2009-02-04T18%3A12%3A21.687Z
&Version=2009-01-01
&Signature=ZQLpf8vEXAMPLE0iC265pf18n0%3D
```

Answer (score 0):

► **Option 1** :

1. Go To : https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/help/help.html/ref=au_1661_cont_help?ie=UTF8&itemID=1661&language=en_US
2. Log with your Amazon account ( even if you don't have seller user ).
3. Press on link : "Inventory File Templates and BTG" ( wait few seconds and it will download the file )

   [Print screen for Option 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPhYx.jpg)

---

► **Option 2 :**

if you are looking for a **CSV File** that contains Amazon departments, categories, sub categories and their links ( based on : https://www.amazon.com/gp/site-directory ) , you may check also in this github repository : https://github.com/postme205/AmzCategoriesSubCategories/ or [Here (github.io)](https://postme205.github.io/Download-List-of-Amazon-Categories-and-subcategories-in-one-csv-file/)